# Using VBA to add cells from different spreadsheets when the sheets haven't been created yet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

I am new to VBA. I am trying to take cell 207 from 12 different sheets and add them so that the sum is placed in another cell on a 13th sheet. I would like to create a for loop of some sort to increment cell indices. This might sound straightforward, but not all of the 12 sheets have been created yet. For example, there are currently five sheets, and I want to click a button on sheet thirteen that adds the sum of cell 207 from all sheets that are present. When an additional sheet is added, this button will automatically update the sum.

This is my code:

```
Sub newMethod()

' declare the double variable
Dim AddEntry


' populate the double variable
 AddEntry = Worksheets("0122").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0222").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0322").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0422").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0522").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0622").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0722").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0822").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("0922").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("1022").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("1122").Range("K207").Value + Worksheets("1222").Range("K207").Value


' Set B5 equal to variable
Range("B5").Value = AddEntry

End Sub
```

There is a syntax error for sure, but I know that the methodology behind the code is completely incorrect. I am not sure how to fix it, or if I am taking a completely incorrect approach.

Just with formulas I accomplished this, but I would have to type out each sheet and I would like to just create some sort of for loop in VBA that increments the cell index.

`= IF(ISNUMBER('0522'!K207),'0522'!K207,0))`

Comment: Change the smart quotes (curly quotes) to straight quotes.

Comment: I tried that. This is my error message: Run-time error '1004'  Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Comment: I would also specify the worksheet using `Worksheets`: i.e. `Range("'0122'!K207")` becomes `Worksheets("0122").Range("K207")`.

Comment: That seemed to do something positive. Now I am getting the error "Run-time error '9' : Subscript out of range"

Comment: I take it this has something to do with the fact that referenced cells do not exist yet

Comment: That means one of your worksheet names is off, or a worksheet with that name does not exist in the currently active workbook. You can only refer to an existing worksheet.

Comment: Do you know if there is away around this? When the worksheets are created, I was hoping that I could create a button that automatically updates the sum so that the user does not have to type a formula

Comment: I'd try a [3D Sum](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sum-multiple-worksheets) maybe. You can use hidden worksheets as "book-ends".

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets  - this link seems to satisfy the idea using sumif. I have no idea how this works and am trying to understand

Comment: = SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'" & sheets & "'!" & "K207"),,INDIRECT("'"&sheets&"'!"&"sumrng"))) - I think something like this might work, but i do not understand the criteria